# Why the JavaScript code fails in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
http://www.luxuryfurclothing.com/
```

I want to make those items (Solutions by need , Solutions by business size ,Solutions by industry) aren't clicked, which are children of `Data Security Solution`, the last menu.

I add the code at the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    var eles = jQuery('li.category51 ul li.level1>a'), i;

    for (i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) {
        eles[i].onclick = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        };
        eles[i].onmouseover = function() {
            this.style.cursor="auto";
        };
    }
</script>
```

This works in Firefox and Chrome, but not IE8.

Comment: Try adding return false; to the onclick.

Comment: First of all, if you have a jQuery object, use a jQuery method to handle event attachment, a la `eles.click(function c(){...});`

Comment: [because of this](http://9gag.com/gag/204028)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** If you want `li.level1>a` to work in IE8, you must specify this DOCTYPE at the start of your document :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

It won't work if you ask your document to be interpreted as `xhtml1`. Besides, there is rarely a reason to use XHTML.

**2)** As mentioned by Shusi, you can't call `preventDefault` on a native IE event. The solution is to use jQuery facilities :

```
$('li.category51 ul li.level1>a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // this is a jquery wrapped event
}).mouseover(function() {
    this.style.cursor="auto";
});
```

Comment: if i don't use li.level1>a .is there a way to get the result with the same effect.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

IE don't support `preventDefault`

you should use `event.returnValue = false;` for IE

implementation:

```
if(event.preventDefault){
  event.preventDefault();
} 
else{
   event.returnValue = false;
}
return false;
```

since you are using jQuery there is a simpler way

```
jQuery.noConflict();
var eles = jQuery('li.category51 ul li.level1>a'), i;
eles.click(function(event) {
        return false;
    }).mouseover(function() {
        this.style.cursor="auto";
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use jQuery for cross browser compability instead of a mix of jQuery and native javascript (at least for event handling)?

```
jQuery('li.category51 ul li.level1>a')
  .click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  })
  .mouseenter(function(event) {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
  });
```

...and why not use CSS to set the cursor?

```
li.category51 ul li.level1>a {
  cursor: auto;
}
```